# Icon position in JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

Is there any posibility of changing Icon image posintion in JButton?

This is how it looks now:

[image]

I want to move the icon more to the left.

I have tried to change the text alignment but it doesn't work as I want:

```
myButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I've added an empty border(you can add any type of border) to the myButton and now it look like that:

[image]

Code:

```
myButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 2, 20));
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at  [JButton.setHorizontalAlignment(int align)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setHorizontalAlignment%28int%29)

> Sets the horizontal alignment of the icon and text. AbstractButton's default is SwingConstants.CENTER, but subclasses such as JCheckBox may use a different default.

you can set:

- SwingConstants.RIGHT
- SwingConstants.LEFT
- SwingConstants.CENTER
- SwingConstants.LEADING
- SwingConstants.TRAILING

Answer (score 3):

You can change the gap of the space between the icon and text with [`setIconTextGap(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIconTextGap-int-). In addition, aligning the contents of the `JButton` towards the left may help with [`setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setHorizontalAlignment-int-).

Comment: @KrzysztofMajewski Did setHorizontalAlignment(left) change anything?

Comment: No. It did not change anything. Tle left "border" is still the same

Comment: @KrzysztofMajewski Are you are calling this method before the overall setVisible() call?