# Align icon of JButton with JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I am working with a `JButton` and wanted to add an icon image to it.
When I went to add an image the image has an offset to the left for some reason.

The image is exactly the same size as the button but it is slightly moved to the left for some reason. (The offset is about 13 pixels)

Here is the code from the button:

```
private JButton getBtnReset() {
    if (btnReset == null) {
        btnReset = new JButton("Reset");
        btnReset.setIcon(new ImageIcon(FrontEnd.class.getResource("/resources/Reset1.png")));
        btnReset.setFont(new Font("OptimusPrinceps", Font.BOLD, 17));
        btnReset.addActionListener(new BtnResetActionListener());
        btnReset.setBounds(400, 11, 167, 69);
    }
    return btnReset;
}
```

Comment: One possible issue might be that you are adding the icon before you set the bounds of the button, messing with the icon placement. Try setting the icon after you have set the bounds of the button. If that does not work, refer to this question and the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640205/icon-position-in-jbutton

Comment: *the image has an offset to the left* - I don't know what that means. An offset to the left to me means that part of the image is cut off and not painted. 1) Don't use setBounds(). Each Swing component should determine its own preferred size and the layout manager will set the size/location. 2) Post the original image on the forum and in image of you GUI.

Comment: JButton [inherits the setHorizontalAlignment method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setHorizontalAlignment(int)).  If you want the image centered in your button, use `btnReset.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER)`.  If you want your image on the left side of the button, use `btnReset.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT)`.

Comment: 1) Post a [mre]. 2) Hotlink to any images needed. 3) Don't use `null` layouts.